SOQL query to get Lead attributes from Account via converted account relation
I'm trying to get the Leads columns from the Account object.
This is the type of query I want to run, but it doesn't work:
SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Name FROM Account.Leads) FROM Account

If I describe the account object, the childRelationships of account has a lead but no relationshipName. Is there a way to perform this query and somehow use the ConvertedAccountId even though the relationshipName is missing?
{
  "cascadeDelete": false,
  "childSObject": "Lead",
  "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
  "field": "ConvertedAccountId",
  "junctionIdListNames": [],
  "junctionReferenceTo": [],
  "relationshipName": null,
  "restrictedDelete": false
}

Doing this works with contacts
SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Name FROM Account.Contacts) FROM Account

{
  "cascadeDelete": true,
  "childSObject": "Contact",
  "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
  "field": "AccountId",
  "junctionIdListNames": [],
  "junctionReferenceTo": [],
  "relationshipName": "Contacts",
  "restrictedDelete": false
}


The relationship is not available in SOQL for some reason.
A possible workaround would be to query the leads directly via the lookup relationship like this:
SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Name, Company FROM Lead WHERE ConvertedAccountId IN (SELECT Id FROM Account)

As a bonus and a good to know, child queries are limited to three times the parent queries resulting child records, this query is not limited in such a way.

Child queries are limited to three times the parent queries, not "100 resulting child records." See Apex Governor Limits.

Thank you! we learn something new every day ;)
